# how to use query result in java

Tags: java

I wrote this query in java that gives me the list of tables and save them in data collection:

```
sql = "select * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'";
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
int count_table = 0;
while (rs.next()) {
    table_list.add(rs.getString(3));
    count_table += 1;
}
Table_list = table_list.toString();
```

Table_list is string.
But when i want to use this list in another query in this way:

```
sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + Table_list[t] + "'";
```

Gives me this error :

```
array required, but java.lang.String found
```

I used this in c# and worked well:

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + tablelist[t].Trim() + "'";
```

What is the same way in java?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Please read up on `PreparedStatement` and use that instead of concatenating query strings, you leave yourself open to SQL injection (and other problems) with your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, brackets access is only allowed for plain arrays. You declare an array using brackets `String[] stringArray`. Internally, Java handles a char array inside the `String`.

Looking at your code, looks like you're confusing a `String` and a `List<String` (or `ArrayList<String>)`.

In order to access to a `List`/`ArrayList` element, you should use `get` method (note that I'm using `table_list`, not `Table_list`):

```
//wrong
sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list[t] + "'";

//right
sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list.get(t).trim() + "'";
```

Note that by doing this, your code is weak to an SQL Injection attack. Instead, you should use `PreparedStatement` to handle this:

```
sql = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = ?";
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, table_list.get(t));
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Also, **please** change the name of your variables, since `table_list` and `Table_list` can be easily confused by code readers (it would result confusing even to you).

Answer (score 1):

```
sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + Table_list[t] + "'";
```

should be changed to:

```
sql="SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '" + table_list.get(t).trim() + "'";
```